# Service containing BroadCastReceiver not functioning correctly

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

> Please see edits before answering!

I have an app which contains a BackgroundService class:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.spotify.music.metadatachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.spotify.music.queuechanged");

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    Log.e("Playing:", "APP IS PLAYING");

    Notification notification = new Notification();
    startForeground(1, notification); 

}

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        long timeSentInMs = intent.getLongExtra("timeSent", 0L);

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.METADATA_CHANGED)) {

            String trackId = intent.getStringExtra("id");
            String artistName = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            String albumName = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            String trackName = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            int trackLengthInSec = intent.getIntExtra("length", 0);


            // Do something with extracted information...

        } else if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED)) {

            boolean playing = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);

            Log.e("Playing:","TRUE");

        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


static final class BroadcastTypes {
    static final String SPOTIFY_PACKAGE = "com.spotify.music";
    static final String PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".playbackstatechanged";
    static final String METADATA_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".metadatachanged";
}


}
```

and this is declared in my manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".BackgroundService"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged" />
            <action android:name="com.spotify.music.metadatachanged" />
            <action android:name="com.spotify.music.queuechanged" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

So essentially my objective is to have my BackgroundService initialized when my app is opened, and to have it continue to run in the Background doing whatever I need it to do. As of now, I am using logs to determine whether my "setup" is working, but when I run my app, I am unable to see an logs even after I tested all actions that should have triggered my BroadCastReceiver. Furthermore, my persistent notification should have changed had my service been running, but it does not...

> **Edit:**:

So, I added logs to my BackgroundService's onCreate() and onReceive() methods, however, neither seem to be appearing. Im wondering, do I need to do something in my launcher activity to initialize the service? Furthermore, no notification is shown so I assume the Service is not being started for some reason...

> **Latest Edit:**

So I added the following code to my Main activity to see if it would make a difference:

```
        startService(new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class));
```

And after debugging my app, I began to see the following error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.aurum.mutify.BackgroundService: java.lang.SecurityException: Isolated process not allowed to call registerReceiver
```

pointing to my BroadCast Receiver class.

Comment: Put log in onReceive() method before long timeSentInMs = intent.getLongExtra("timeSent", 0L); , just to check whether it is capturing the broadcast.

Comment: @avinashthakur I took your suggestion and added logs in the onCreate() and onReceive() methods, however neither one is shown when I run my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent services are designed for short tasks. And your intent handling method is empty.

If you need long running task in the background use standard service and call start foreground. This will minimize chance of system destroying your service.

To learn more go [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

EDIT

Try overriding onStartCommand method. this method is called when service is started and usually you do all stuff here. Remember that there are 3 options to return.

Edit 2:
try something like this
in on create

```
PendingIntent pi;
BroadcastReceiver br;
Intent myIntent;

 @Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
    super.onCreate();

     myIntent = new Intent("something")


   if(Build.Version.SDK_INT >= 16)     //The flag we used here was only added at API 16    
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
    //use myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND); if you want to add more than one flag to this intent;

    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, myIntent, 0); 

    br = new BroadcastReceiver ()
    {
      public void onReceive (Context context, Intent i) {
        new thread(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            //do something
          }
        }).start();
      }
    };
```

And then in on start command

```
 this.registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("something"));
```

Comment: I am still getting: java.lang.SecurityException: Isolated process not allowed to call registerReceiver after moving my code from onCreate() to onStartCommand()

Comment: Updated my answear, are you shure you are not using remote process?

Comment: for some reason, this seemed to do the trick. I appreciate the help

Comment: There was some change in api 16 related to how this works :)